# Hibernate annotation for auto increment but should also save the value if we set it before save

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a table (PostgreSQL) with 2 auto increment fields, the first one is  annotated with @Id and @GeneratedValue, the 2nd one should auto increment and save it, until I set it on purpose.

Is there any way to do this?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "route")
public class Route extends BaseEntity {

 private Integer id;
 private Integer routeNumberId;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "id")
 public Integer getId() {
    return id;
 }
 ...
 @XmlAttribute
 @Id
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="route_number_seq")
 @GenericGenerator(name="route_number_seq",
                   strategy="com.tripms.models.master.UseIdOrGenerate")
 @Column(name = "route_number_id", nullable = false)
 public Integer getRouteNumberId() {
     return routeNumberId;
 }

}
```

I can't annotate @Id twice and I don't want a composite pk.

Comment: did you try to code something?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. You need to post some code to show your effort towards what are you trying to achieve. This will also help other users to answer your question.

Comment: i have updated it.. @SouravGhosh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing auto-increment and manual values is not a good idea. How should your database behave, when your current sequence points to lets say 11, but you insert an entry with value 20? Once the sequence reaches 20, you would get unique constraint violation. In order to prevent it, you would have to verify that the generated sequence value is not in conflict with any existing entry - which is going to introduce whole bunch of other problems with retry, locking etc.

It might be good idea to rethink your model or requirements, why do you the second pseudo Id? And why should it be possible to fill it both manually and automatically?
if you insist on this feature, you can get it working, if you guarantee, that the manual entries do not collide with the auto-generated ones. Then you can create a custom ID generator for your ,,real ID" column (Integer id) and override the `generate` method, so that apart from generating the ID you also check the value of your ,,pseudo Id" (routeNumberId). If it is `null`, you can ask the DB to give you next value from some sequence. Dummy implementation bellow:

```
@Override
public synchronized Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {
    Serializable result;
    if (object instanceof Route ) {
        Route reoute= ((Route ) object);
        if (route.getid() != null) {
            result = (Serializable) route.getId();
        } else {
            result = <GENERATE new ID(e.g. call super, etc)> ;
        }
        if (route.getRouteNumberId() == null) {
            long autoIncrRouteId = <GENERATE new routeID,>
            route.setRouteNumberId(autoIncrRouteId );
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        result = super.generate(session, object);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Another option is to use @PrePersist entity listener and do the check and/or sequence call there. However it might be tricky to access Entity manager or JPA context from the listeners, as most JPA providers do not fully support injection into entity listeners. You might do a manual jndi lookup, but first rethink what you are trying to achieve if it is worth the trouble.

Edit: functional Id generator code(postgres).

```
@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object obj) throws HibernateException {
    Connection connection = session.connection();
    try {
        Route route= ((Route ) obj);
        String seqName = "you_db_id_sequence";
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT nextval ('" + seqName + "') as nextval");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("nextval");
            log.info("Generated order id {} ", id);
            if (route.getRouteNumberId() == null) {
                route.setrouteNumberid(id); //or call another sequence to get a different id 
            }
            return Long.parseLong(code);
        } else {
           throw new IllegalStateException("could not generate new id");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Could not generate id!", e);
        throw new HibernateException("Unable to generate id from Sequence");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The reason why i want routeNumberId to be able to add manually - > while saving records of the route both should auto increment.. and there is one condition where i need to make whole copy of the record with same routeNumberId(coz this is Fk to other tables) and also need previous record for audits and will also store old records routeNumberId in its some other column..  so it will not give the problem u mentioned about unique constraint violation coz anyway i will  be using routeNumberId which is already generated..

Comment: code u gave above only works for Id.... i need it for routeNumberId.. it wont work on routeNumberId coz i it allow me to annotate @ Id on both of them... this code works if annotated with @ Id only

Comment: If routeNumberId is a FK to another table, than it should be an association `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne` not an auto-incremented integer. The code provided will fill both Id and routeNumberId even though the generator is only the `Integer Id` field. Of course, you can not have two columns annotated with `@Id` unless you want a compound PK.   In any case, if routeNumberId is FK to another entity, then your model should reflect that.

Comment: can u tell me how can i generate RouteNumberId in that Generate class..??    or i can even use id as my RouteNumberId .. just give me how do i do that

Comment: I have edited the answer to give you the code. But for the sake of your future self, I ask you to reconsider the routeNumberId and your copy use case :)